# GPG key expiration and storage

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

I hope I came to right place to ask about GPG.

I have created secret, public, and sign keys and set expiration dates for all keys in case I lose an access to them or forget a keyphrase, etc. I have read the [GPG manual](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/book1.html) and a couple of blogs (e.g. [this one](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/11/gpg-encryption-guide-part-1.html)) but I did not find answers to my questions.

1. What is the best way to store the keys if I have to reinstall a system?
2. Can I still have an access to expired keys and e.g. decrypt old files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the keys are protected by a good passphrase and export them to some trusted storage, such as USB stick.
2. Yes. You can even change expiration date of your keys just for yourself to make them valid again.

Comment: Thansk Peter. No Dropbo,  then!